# Switching between open pdfs in Preview without losing your place

Tags: pdf, preview

[image: Multiple PDFs open in preview]

If I have multiple PDFs open in preview, as shown with the "table of contents" sidebar, if I click on one of the other documents and then return to the current document, it returns me to page 1 instead of the page I'm on (in this case, page 9). Is there any way to have preview return me to the page I'm on?

Comment: Only if you have the Thumbnails view and then expand.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Option+Page Up/Down. Or on a Macbook, Fn + Option + Arrow Up/Down

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the answer you provided will solve the problem or is better than others out there.  Providing links can also help the OP, and others, find additional info for themselves.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK only with a work-around:

1. add a bookmark with <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> in your currently visible PDF
2. choose another PDF read a bit and add a second bookmark there
3. switch to bookmark view with <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>5</kbd>
4. choose the bookmark of your first PDF in the sidebar
   You may delete the bookmark using the context menu

   [image: example]

Answer (score 0):

This might just be personal preference, but when I am working with multiple PDFs in Preview, I generally have them open in separate windows.

Say you have three PDFs open, each in their own Preview window. Then you can use <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>~</kbd> to switch between active windows. Since they are all open in their own window, you will never lose your place in any of the documents.

The <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>~</kbd> shortcut works for any application you have open, which has more than one window open, AFAIK.

If you are set on keeping all of the PDFs under one Preview window, I think klanomath's suggestion would be your best bet.